# Unexpected html anchor redirection

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, markup

I'm currently developing a large project (and I don't know the whole codebase in detail), and I just stumbled upon something I can't understand and hopefully someone can add some advise.

In my project we use a "to top"-anchor to easily get from bottom to top (nothing special). But for some reasons, it won't work like I expect. Imagine an URL like: http://example.com/foo and the following html:

```html
<header id="top">top</header>
<div style="height: 2000px"></div>
<a href="#top">Click me</a>
```

In theory this works fine and heads to http://example.com/foo#top without reloading the site, but on my project it will redirect to http://example.com/#top.

I can't see any EventListener made by Javascript which may intercept the click event. Does anyone got some hints for me which might be wrong (or I just miss)?

Comment: Running this on Apache server? I would take a look at the .htaccess file in that case, and see if there are any QUERY or REQUEST modifiers which might explain this.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238688/href-redirects-to-the-index-page-but-not-to-the-current-pages-top

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], pay particular attention to the section marked "Divide and conquer".

Comment: Thank you @AmrElgarhy, this does help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AmrElgarhy, I'll leave an answer to my own question here.

It's because of the `<base>` element in my HTML code.
For my solution I can't delete this node, but I'm going to add the request-uri to my "to-top"-anchor programmatically like this:

```html
<header id="top">top</header>
<div style="height: 2000px"></div>
<a href="{{ request.uri }}#top">Click me</a>
```

Whereas `{{ request.uri }}` will contain `/foo` or similar.