# Can I use relative <a href=#foo> and go to a named anchor on the current page when when <base> is being used?

Tags: html, tags, href, anchor

If I have a page [www.example1.com/foo/test.html](http://www.example1.com/foo/test.html) as follows:

```
<head>
<base href=http://www.example2.com/>
</head>
<body>
<a href=#foo>foo</a>
...
<a name=foo />
</body>
```

Then when I click "foo" it takes me to http://www.example2.com/#foo instead of the current page's foo.  I suppose this sort of makes sense, but is there a way to do a page-local named anchor jump when `<base>` points somewhere else?

Note that test.html is named named dynamically, so an absolute path in the href=...#foo isn't an option.  Some JS could be, but strait html would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior,  documentation says that all relative links are relative to  including anchors:

- http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

See also:

- [href="#" redirects to the index page but not to the current page's top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238688/href-redirects-to-the-index-page-but-not-to-the-current-pages-top)